# アカウントにログイン資格情報を追加したら、別アカウントが作成されてしまったように見える

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, アカウント

> アカウントにログイン資格情報を追加または削除する方法は?

で、ログイン方法の追加を調べたのですが、この記述(画面イメージ)が現在の設定と合っていなく、(日本語版?) それらしき場所で、
 個人情報 - サイト設定 - ログイン情報で、アカウントを追加したところ、別ユーザーとして登録がされたようです。 既存ユーザーで追加のログイン方法を追加する事はできないのでしょうか?

**追記: (4/15)**
少し前に、別ユーザーとして登録したアカウントとの統合をして頂きました。個人的には、問題解決ですが、質問の主旨についての解決には全くなってない感じ。ヘルプについても変わらずのようです。

Comment: ヘルプセンターの[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)でしょうか。確かに本家の[対応するページ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)とは記述が異なるように見えますね……。

Comment: よく greentea さんの状況が分かっていませんが、分かれてしまったアカウントのマージは[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)から行うことができます。（ただ、おそらくそういうことでは無いのですよね……？）

Comment: 関係ないかもしれませんけどそのマーク結構好きです。

Comment: **_ヘルプセンターのこちらでしょうか。_ ** こちらの箇所を探すことがでませんでした。本家と日本語版の違い? こちらも直して欲しいと思います。

Comment: OpenID を追加しようとなさったのであれば、最近 OpenID が廃止されようとしている流れのどれかにひっかかったのかもしれません: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/341401

Comment: OpenIDの意味がよく分かりません。。。。 最初、GoogleIDで登録したのですが、日常的に使っていないので、ログインが二度手間となっていました。直接、ログインしたいと思った次第。

Comment: ヘルプセンターの和訳が本家のアカウント追加ページに合わせられ適用済みであることを確認しました。

日：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

英：https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ヘルプセンターの和訳が本家のアカウント追加ページに合わせられ適用済みであることを確認しました。

更新されている事を確認しました。
実際に有効かどうかは確認するすべがありませんので、終了としたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

2018年3月現在、ウェブ版のプロフィール画面から「設定」→「ログイン設定」と遷移するとそれらしき設定画面に移ることができました。私自身は行ったことがないのですが、ここから設定できませんでしょうか？

[image: 「ログイン設定」画面のスクリーンショットです。下の方に「アカウントを追加」というボタンがあります。]

Comment: 上記の画面で、アカウントを追加したところ、別ID(多分) で登録されました。  ユーザー画面で、"greentea" を検索すると　2人出てくると思います。

Comment: たしかにお二方出てきますね。モデレータの方々の意見も出てこないので、ヘルプにも書いてあるとおり当面は直接運営にコンタクトを取るのが良さそうです。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: それとは別に、このヘルプの内容を調べる必要がありそうです。確かヘルプは Transifex では翻訳できなかったはずなので、モデレータの方の協力が必要なのかもしれません。

Comment: 別の質問にコメントしたように、ログインの追加について問合せメールしましたが、返事がありませんでした。

Comment: @greentea CM チームに再度連絡をいたしました。２つのアカウントが確認され次第対応されると思いますのでしばしお待ちいただけますでしょうか。

Comment: メールが来ました。結果を待ちたいと思います。